# granting permission to all tables in db SYBASE

Tags: database, permissions, sybase

Apologies for this question but I can't find proper answer on the web.
I'm looking for query that grants all permissions to all objects in db(tables,sps, sys tables). I've tried multiple combination of grant all .... to  user_name but can't find proper phrase. I'm working on SYBASE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
select 'grant all on ' + name + ' to <user_name>' from sysobjects where type = 'U' or type = 'P'
go
```

and use the query output to grant all necessary permission to all the tables and sps in db. If you have a better answer, please share.

Answer (score 2):

grant select any table to "user_name"; ---for SAP(Sybase) IQ

Comment: This query gives the grant on all tables in all users. what if I want to grant select on a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for a power user, you can also alias the username to 'dbo'

```
use DATABASE_NAME
go
sp_dropuser user_name
go
sp_addalias user_name,dbo
go
```